# Using element to element binding in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, mvvm

I don't really see the need for element to element binding in Silverlight 3 if using MVVM. Won't having one property directly affect another proper cause that property to be untestable?

To me, it makes more sense to do a two way binding to a explicit property defined in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that the use of MVVM severely deflates the usefulness of element to element binding.

Still, if all you are doing is binding two elements using a ViewModel property... what can you test?  You can test that setting a property in the ViewModel sends a PropertyChanged event... but thats about it.  Only when something else cares about that value is it useful to test a property like that.

In the simple cases, I can see element2element binding being more efficient and less code.